# Why does this code (malloc) not generate heap corruption?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a, b;
};

struct B
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    A * pa = (A *)malloc(sizeof(B));
    int c = 5;
    pa -> a = 3;
    cout << pa -> a << endl;
    pa -> b = 0;
    cout << pa -> b << endl;
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I run this code with VC++ 2012. It doesn't generate any error message.

I think pa -> b will access memory block outbound. Heap corruption should occur!
But actually, nothing happened in both debug and release modes.

But since int c immediately follows A * pa;
I think in memory, pa -> b will access int c.

The output of the program is:
3
4
5

Can anyone help explain this?

---

If I add "free(pa);" at the end of the main:
+under debug mode, it will cause HEAP CORRUPTION ERROR.
+under release mode, nothing still happens.

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything can happen.

Comment: How are you determining that the heap isn't corrupted in some way?

In general you can't expect an error message for this. Sometimes the runtime can detect corruption and warn you but the runtime can't and doesn't detect every instance of writing outside of memory bounds.

Comment: Probably this is due to structure packing for alignment masking the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. Undefined means anything possible.

Comment: Heap corruption detection is not part of the standard, and those who created this detection mechanism tried their best to inform the user about the problem.

Comment: Your reasoning about the `pa->b` access corrupting `c` is incorrect. This is because `pa` is pointing to memory on the heap, while `c` lives on the stack, so `c` is in a totally different region of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means that anything can happen. In particular, no diagnostic is required.

One practical way to find bugs of this type is by using a tool like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/):

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
a=3
==37240== Invalid write of size 4
==37240==    at 0x100000E1D: main (test.c:22)
==37240==  Address 0x10001b184 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==37240==    at 0x5237: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37240==    by 0x100000DD2: main (test.c:19)
==37240== 
==37240== Invalid read of size 4
==37240==    at 0x100000E28: main (test.c:23)
==37240==  Address 0x10001b184 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==37240==    at 0x5237: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==37240==    by 0x100000DD2: main (test.c:19)
==37240==
```

There are similar tools for Windows: [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Comment: This tool "valgrind" seems only work under linux system. I am using windows now.

Comment: Is there any useful tools under Windows platform?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: Yes, there is, and you are already using it: Visual Studio. You just have to call `free(pa)` when you're done with the object. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Heap corruption can only be detected when you enter some heap function. In this case you enter a heap function only at the beginning, when heap is still uncorrupted. Try to delete structure pointed to `pa` before returning from `main`, and see what happens.

Comment: You are right. After i insert a "free(pa)" at the end of the program, error occurs! Debug error! HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED! CRT detects wrote to memory after the end of heap.

Comment: Heap corruption detection is only performed in debug build. In release builds it's removed for performance reasons. For more details please visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I also heard that the heap under debug and release mode is different! Heap under debug will allocate more memory as specified by programmer.